# How to reduce voltage from a battery to a motor

Tags: voltage, batteries, resistors, diodes, amperage

I have a 14.8v battery and I want to run a motor on 13v. What is the best solution to reduce the voltage from 14.8v to 13v?

Comment: What current does the motor need (stall current is the best figure I reckon)

Comment: Why 13V exactly? Motors generally have a range of few volts either side of the nominal they are quite happy to run with. You might be able to run your motor with a direct connection.

Comment: Insufficient participation.  Questions for more info are not answered by the O.P.  Not off-topic, though.

Answer (score 1):

most motor it is possible to power 40% more but if you want to reduce voltage in a easy way, a diode reduce 0,7 V, some only 0,5 V, so you can (if DC) a disode in serial or if AC 2 anti-parallel diode in serial to the motor

its not exact, not best, but cheap and easy

Answer (score 0):

The very best way to reduce the battery voltage in this case, if you really do need 13V for the motor, is to use a switching regulator. You can build your own DC-DC converter to do this. Check the web sites of vendors like TI and Linear Technology. THey have a plethora of different chips that can be deployed to build the circuit that you will need. TI has a very nice "web bench" design aid to help you select a proper part and will even suggest additional components that you will put around the DC-DC converter power supply chip.

The sitching type design is optimum becasue you should be able to achieve better than 80 -> 85% efficiency in the power conversion rather than generating a lot of heat like some other approaches would create.

If you want to purchase a ready made model of a DC-DC converter that may work for your application you can look for something [like this on eBay](http://www.robotmesh.com/dc-dc-power-module-25w). This one can convert anything from 3.6->25V to a selectable output between 3.3 and 25V with a claimed 5A rating for current.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I Offer to Use MC34063 . This Regulator Convert [3 to 40] Volt ----> [3 to 40] Volt . For Example You Can Convert 5v To 18v Or Can Convert 18v To 5v. (BOOST , BUCK , Invert) Switch .
with High Output Current Switch (1.5 Amp).

You Can Use LM2576 ... But This Regulator is So Expensive.

Answer (score -6):

Use a voltage divider if you really need it, 500k and 300k resistor.

Comment: Voltage divider is very very bad approach. Heat dissipation as well as low current. This is incorrect solution. A switching regulator is needed.

Comment: A voltage divider will not work well when the current load is large (with respect to the unloaded divider current) and varying. To make it work you would need much lower resistor values which would waste much power.